# How do I know if my H1B is transferable?

Tags: usa, visa, h1-visa

I work as a faculty in a university in USA. My H1B was filed by my university, and was approved in last October 2015.

As I recently interviewed a company, the new employer wanted to know if my H1B is transferable (to the new industry employer).

How do I know this? Does my H1B approval notice has any code to tell me this? If not, what exactly should I ask to my lawyer (who processed my H1B) to learn this?

Comment: Related: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/324/how-to-change-employers-on-a-h-1b-visa-in-the-united-states

Answer (score 5):

> My H1B was filed by my university, and was approved in last October 2015.

That's how. There was no quota in October 2015 available, i.e.: your H1b wasn't subject to quota. You cannot transfer non-quota H1b to a quota H1b.

This is also part of the H1b paperwork (shows as cap-exempt or something like that in the documents).